# How to change fontstyle in Beamerposter

Tags: beamer, posters

I am currently working on making a conference poster based on an overleaf [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/landscape-beamer-poster-template/vjpmsxxdvtqk#.WysgiRJKhPM) for math research, and am hoping to change the font of my poster to amsmath/Computer Modern instead of what it is right now.

Within the template there are two .sty files: one is `beamerposter.sty`, and the other is `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`. Which component of which file should I edit so that the font changes? Sorry if this seems obvious, and thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

These files already load `lmodern` Latin Modern, which is an enhanced version of Computer Modern, so you don't really need to make any further changes.

Unless you mean you want the poster title and author to be set in serif, instead of the current non-serif: then you can add this in your `.tex`'s preamble (just before `\begin{document}` would be fine):

```
\setbeamerfont{headline}{family=\rmfamily}
```

There is no need to modify the `.sty` files.

Comment: I am more concerned with the display of equations under Latin Modern, namely cases, because the brackets are too flat. I'm looking for changes where those brackets were more normally displayed.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, Overleaf (or rather, latexmk) automatically picks it up. I've added an answer there; thanks for the invite. I guess this comment (and yours) can then be deleted to keep this section clean.